# hiding the scrollbar from the DIV

Tags: html, css

I am working with `div` which is throwing an additional `scrollbar` which I don't want to have. I want my `div` to be of flexible width (bootstrap) and fixed height of `290px`. Can someone please help me out of this ?

```
<div class="box">
  <atitle>This is box 2</atitle>
  <hr>
    <div class="box1">
      <p>Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS is here :

```
.box {
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 290px;
  border: 1px solid #383737;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background-color: #3d3d3d;
}

.box1 {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 290px;
}
```

Comment: for which div you don't need to show the scrollbar ? box or box1 ?

Comment: Replace overflow: auto; by overflow: hidden; on .box1 or provide better explanation

Comment: @FrebinFrancis : on box1

Comment: then set .box1 {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 290px;
}

Comment: @Ianis : by adding hidden, issue won't resolve, because my issue is to visually remove scrollbar but the functionality of scrolling should remain in div.

Comment: Look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-still-being-able-to-scroll

Comment: @FrebinFrancis that way i wont be able to see the scrollbar, it's fine. But i want the functionalities of scroll. 
my Issue is just to hide the scrollBAR

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/H27BK/ check this one

Comment: @FrebinFrancis : In this fiddle, the width is declared, i can't do that as i am using bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you:

```
.box1{
    width: 100%;
    height: 99%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

.box{
    height: 99%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: if you don't want the scroll bars set a `width` and `max-width`

Comment: I cant set width, I am using bootstrap :( 
setting width would be difficult for all devices

Comment: set **max-width** only

Comment: define **max-width** and **width** (if possible) in % to be compatible with devices